# Как подсчитать сумму ячеек в строке dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Нужно подсчитать сумму ячеек для каждой строки таблицы dataGridView. Кол-во строк и столбцов заранее не известно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы его получаете откуда-то или вводите с клавиатуры?

Comment: DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value вернет значение 1-ой ячейки 1-го столбца. Дальше нужно будет немного подумать вам